# How far have we got towards proving Catalan's constant is irrational?

Tags: analysis, irrational-numbers, catalans-constant

While it is not know if Catalan's constant is irrational,what progress has been made on this problem?For example is there a reformulation of the problem ? (this maybe a criteria, using continued fractions, that can be used to prove if Catalan's constant is irrational-or a different reformulation not using continued fractions).

Comment: [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)

Comment: The singular is *criterion* – "criteria" is the plural.